# SEO - handling "duplicate" content on search engine

Tags: seo

My site is a search engine for jobs - it crawls website where jobs posted and indexing that content (similar to indeed.com, for example).

I notice that my website constantly has low SEO rating (e.g. I just not getting traffic, despite the fact that I displaying very quality and useful content).

Obviously, since my website is a search engine, it has no content of its own - all content comes from other websites (job boards, agencies, job postings of employers, etc).

I suspect that my low SEO ranking is due to fact that all content on website is "duplicate" - coming from other websites.

Am I right about my suspicions? Is there something I can do about (e.g. some best practices for such scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes of low search rank or its absence for your website:

- According to Manual Actions report of Google - **[Thin content with little or no added value](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604824?hl=en)**: **[Automatically generated content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306)** and **[Scraped content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721312)** is a violation of the Google recommendations.
- According to **[Little or no original content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66361?hl=en)** of Google: Autogenerated content - also is a violation of the Google recommendations.